# What have the harasser said to Rana

Tags: dialogue, the-salesman

In the end of the Asghar Farhadi's *The Salesman*,  when harasser's family came after him, before leaving the apartment he turned to Rana and said something unintelligible. I've downloaded several subtitles in different languages but this phrase hasn't been translated in any of them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He looks back at Rana and says "forgive me". the word is

> ببخشید   pronounced "bebakhshid"

which is most commonly used as "excuse me" and it's so common to be said in various situations. In everyday language asking for forgiveness is usually said in a slight variation of this word(includes the object me) and so when the family hear him saying this word they just regard it as a form of being polite, rather than its literal meaning.